# How to select all these words in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, ado.net

[image]

I want to change all these 'int' to 'bool',
in VSCode ，the shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,
What is the shortcut in VisualStudio 2017？

Comment: Please post code as *text* rather than screenshots. But are you asking for anything more than "What's the shortcut for search and replace"?

Comment: Why not change in VSCode and save the file? Visual Studio will load the saved file :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ? What would suit best the case if refactor-renaming, making all the usage of your selection change with it too, so you don't need to change it all by hand or overwrite content which is spelled identically but which should have not been targeted. If ever in need of a binding, keep this [Visual Studio Binding Cheat Sheet](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/)

Comment: @haohu No problem, glad to help. On a side note, avoid using Images for anything here, it's content can not be used for SO/Google searches etc.. making all the content in the Image "Lost".

Answer (score 1):

Search and replace in a given file `CTRL + H`

Search and replace in all files for a solution `CTRL + SHIFT + H`

Not entirely sure this is what you need, but this should be able to help you :)

Comment: Look at @Antry answer :)

Answer (score 0):

cmd + shift + L when selecting the element of which you want select all ocurrences